# Heroku meme api gives me application error

Tags: heroku, discord.js

So I've been using heroku meme api on my discord js bot, it was working fine untill today when it didn't respond I decided to check the website but when I opened it it gave me an application error, idk how to fix it any help would be appreciated the link I use is
`https://meme-api.herokuapp.com/gimme`

Comment: This post is unrelated to discord.js, please refrain from using incorrect tags.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Heroku has discontinued free dynos and data services, it's possible that API was using those.

https://blog.heroku.com/next-chapter

Answer (score 1):

The new link for the API  is https://meme-api.com/gimme

hope this helps